# Multiple occurances of delimeters within a HTML template

Tags: php, regex, substr, strpos

I am facing a problem that I can't get my head around. I thought I would turn to the experts once again to shine some light.

I have a HTML template and within the template I have delimiters like:

`[has_image]<p>The image is <img src="" /></p>[/has_image]`

These delimiters may have multiple occurances within the template and below is what I am trying to achieve:

- Find all occurances of these delimiters and replace the content between these delimiters with an image source or replace it empty if image doesn't exist but still keep the value/content of the remaining template.

Below is my code that works only for one occurance but struggling to accomplish it for multiple occurances.

```
function replace_text_template($template_body, $start_tag, $end_tag, $replacement = ''){
    $occurances = substr_count($template_body, $start_tag);
    $x = 1;

    while($x <= $occurances) {      
        $start = strpos($template_body, $start_tag);
        $stop = strpos($template_body, $end_tag);

        $template_body = substr($template_body, 0, $start) . $start_tag . $replacement . substr($template_body, $stop);     
        $x++;   
    }

    return $template_body;
}

$template_body will have HTML code with delimiters

replace_text_template($template_body, "[has_image]", "[/has_image]");
```

Whether I remove the while loop it still works for a single delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the problem. If anybody finds this useful please feel free to use the code. However, if anyone finds a better way please do share it.

```
function replace_text_template($template_body, $start_tag, $end_tag, $replacement = ''){
    $occurances = substr_count($template_body, $start_tag);
    $x = 1;

    while($x <= $occurances) {      
        $start = strpos($template_body, $start_tag);
        $stop = strpos($template_body, $end_tag);           
        $template_body = substr($template_body, 0, $start) . $start_tag . $replacement . substr($template_body, $stop);     
        $template_body = str_replace($start_tag.''.$end_tag, '', $template_body); // replace the tags so on next loop the position will be correct
        $x++;   
    }

    return $template_body;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function replace_text_template($template_body, $start_tag, $replacement = '') {
    return preg_replace_callback("~\[".preg_quote($start_tag)."\].*?\[\/".preg_quote($start_tag)."\]~i", function ($matches) use ($replacement) {
        if(preg_match('~<img.*?src="([^"]+)"~i', $matches[0], $match)) {
            if (is_array(getimagesize($match[1]))) return $match[1];
        }
        return $replacement;
    }, $template_body);
}

$template_body = <<<EOL
text
[has_image]<p>The image is <img src="" /></p>[/has_image]

abc [has_image]<p>The image is <img src="http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/themes/se-company/images/logo.png" /></p>[/has_image]xyz
EOL;

echo replace_text_template($template_body, "has_image", "replacement");
```

Returns:

```
text
replacement

abc http://blog.stackoverflow.com/wp-content/themes/se-company/images/logo.pngxyz
```